# Accepting data for as long as the user wishes

Tags: c++

I am working on a project related to supermarket billing. I would like to know how to accept data from the user for as long as he. My current code is as below:

```
#include < stdio.h > 
#include < iostream.h > 
#include < conio.h >

class product //start of class
{

    int itemno;
    char name[100];
    char itemtype[50];
    float price;
    float quantity;
    float total;

    public:

    void addprod();
    void calculate();
    void accept();
    void display();

}; //end of class

void product::addprod() //starting of addproduct()
{
    cout << "enter the name of the poduct:";
    gets(name);

    cout << "enter its type:";
    gets(itemtype);

    cout << "enter its price:";
    cin >> price;

} //end of addproduct()

void product::accept() //starting of accept()
{
    cout << "enter the item name:";
    gets(name);

    cout << "enter the quantity:";
    cin >> quantity;

}

void product::calculate() {
    total = price * quantity;
}

void product::display() {
    cout << "\nName";
    cout << name;

    cout << "\nPrice";
    cout << price;
    cout << "\nquantity";
    cout << quantity;
    cout << "\ntotal\n\n\n\n\n";
    cout << total;

}

void main() {
    product s1[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        s1[i].addprod();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        s1[i].accept();

    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        s1[i].calculate();

    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        s1[i].display();

    }
}
```

My `main()` accepts everything 3 times but I want it to select everything for as long as the user wants. How can I achieve this?

Pls check this......

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<iostream.h>
 #include<conio.h>
  int i;

 class product           //start of class
    {


            int itemno;
            char name[100];
            char itemtype[50];
            float price;
            float quantity;
            float total;


            public:

            void addprod() ;
            void calculate();
            void accept();
            void display()   ;




     }    ;                 //end of class




     void product::addprod()   //starting of addproduct()
        {
            cout<<"enter the name of the poduct:";
            gets(name)   ;

            cout<<"enter its type:";
            gets(itemtype);

            cout<<"enter its price:";
            cin>>price;

        }                                       //end of addproduct()



     void product::accept()           //starting of accept()
     {
            cout<<"enter the item name:";
            gets(name)  ;


            cout<<"enter the quantity:";
            cin>>quantity;

     }




     void    product::calculate()
        {
                    total=price*quantity;
         }



     void product::display()
        {
                cout<<"\nName";
                cout<<name;

                cout<<"\nPrice";
                cout<<price ;
                cout<<"\nquantity";
                 cout<<quantity;
                 cout<<"\ntotal\n\n\n\n\n";
                cout<<total;

        }





        void main()
        {
         int ch;
         product s1[3];



         cout<<"\n      1.      Add product";
         cout<<"\n     2.      Make Bill";
         cout<<"\n     3.      Display Bill";
         cout<<"\n     0.      Exit";
         cout<<"\n     Enter your choise(1,2,3,9)"     ;
         cin>>ch;


         switch(ch)
         {

         case 1:          cout<<"\n press 0 to exit";
                                 for(i=1;i!=0;i++)
                                s1[i].addprod();
                                break;
            }
```

}

Comment: Did you consider asking the user to input whether or not they want to enter another product, and then decide based on that whether to loop round again or exit?

Comment: Oh my god, you're using `gets()`. **DON'T DO IT**. Use std::string and getline instead.

Comment: Friends is just a small fragment of the program.....i have made a menu and using switch case it do the respective job

Comment: I am new to c++ and now just few header files...i work  on Turbo C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your code and as far as I understand, you need to have a do-while loop in your main. Here is a demonstration.

```
Do {  
  here goes your main code....... 
  Cout<<"do you want to add more data? "; 
  char ans;
  cin>>ans; 
}while(ans!=n);
```

Now it will run untill the user inputs 'n'.
Hope it would b useful.

Comment: Thnx Hussain....i have that type of idea....but i wanted a different way of doing it....all my classmate would be using this method only.....like in real software's escape key is use to go back...i like to do the same

Comment: cout<<"\n press n to exit\n\n";
         char con='y';
         while(con=='y')
         {
         s1[i].addprod();
         i++;
         cout<<"do u wanna continue(y\n)";
         cin>>con;


           if(con=='n')
           {
           goto a;
                                 }
         }

         break;

Comment: I am also a student of C++ and am not that much expert. but i think you should run do-while loop in your switch statements.  I prefer this do-while loop as it takes input atleast once. further choice is left with the user. if you make me clear, what exactly is your aim, I may prove helpful.

Comment: if you want your function to work with escape, you can use ASCII code of escape key for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Some advice for a good grade, as I did my project 3 years back :)

- You need to make a menu
- You need to add some input validation
- You need to add a few more options as well. My project had run into ~300 lines

For program runs dependent on user input, you need to input a variable and then use that for controlling your loops.

However, i strongly suggest, that you convert this into a menu driven program if you want a good grade. That will automatically solve this problem.

Comment: Hi AshRj...thnx for the answer....menu is all made but i needed the logic.....like can u give me a code fragment....like if users add 1products and then he wanna stop....how should i do it

Comment: If ".menu is all made " then you simply need to call the menu repeatedly, till user decides to exit. You have to add an option to exit in the menu itself.

Comment: i have tried it but its not working....i will comment my fragment soon